UNABLE TO START MYSQL (MAS OS M3)
Not able to start mysql Installed using mysql dmg installer ,
These are the logs:
4-11-28T21:42:41.329831Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '9.1.0'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-11-28T21:42:54.609324Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start. 
2024-11-28T21:42:54.750021Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013711] [Server] Manifest file '/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.my' is not read-only. For better security, please make sure that the file is read-only.
2024-11-28T21:42:54.751534Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 9.1.0) starting as process 13863
2024-11-28T21:42:54.753485Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2024-11-28T21:42:54.757772Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-11-28T21:42:54.903258Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended. 
2024-11-28T21:42:54.940363Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2024-11-28T21:42:54.941815Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2024-11-28T21:42:55.001963Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-11-28T21:42:55.001981Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-11-28T21:42:55.008311Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /tmp/mysqlx.sock
2024-11-28T21:42:55.008326Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '9.1.0'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-11-29T01:06:09.579769Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 9.1.0).
2024-11-29T01:06:11.583732Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 10  user: 'root'.
2024-11-29T01:06:11.583982Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 12  user: 'root'.
2024-11-29T01:06:11.584366Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 13  user: 'root'.
2024-11-29T01:06:11.584550Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 14  user: 'root'.
2024-11-29T01:06:12.364633Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 9.1.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-11-29T01:06:12.364649Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.

I am trying to restart but it's failing with PID file not found and err file doesnt contain sufficient info
  prashant@PRASHANTs-MacBook-Air mysql % sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
    
     ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
    Starting MySQL
    .Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/PRASHANTs-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
     ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/PRASHANTs-MacBook-Air.local.pid).
    
    
        prashant@PRASHANTs-MacBook-Air data % tail -100f mysqld.local.err 
   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 12  user: 'root'.
        2024-11-29T02:33:16.884477Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 13  user: 'root'.
        2024-11-29T02:33:16.884736Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 15  user: 'root'.
        2024-11-29T02:33:17.411522Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 9.1.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
        2024-11-29T02:33:17.411555Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.


that says some one is shutting down the service, also you should search for the mysql error log, if it has something interesting

can't find anything from log

in the log? then show it here please .

Updated above please check

that is because mysql hasn't even startet, look at the duplicate thread for pointers
